# Linux server not able to run any command of apt-get , sudo , su -?

Tags: apt, server, ssh, sudo, ejabberd

I'm using server with SSH access. I'm trying to install ejabberd with command but it is not working. I manage to install it without sudo.
For installing i follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300202/7365127).

Errors while starting ejabberd:

```
$ ./ejabberdctl start
/home/sancm/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sancm/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory

$ ./ejabberdctl status
./ejabberdctl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sanchr5m/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sanchr5m/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
./ejabberdctl: line 125: 3009909 Aborted      

       "$@"
```

On my server `apt-get` and `sudo`, `su` are not working.  I don't know why.

> free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32043      29812       2230         19       3624      10701
-/+ buffers/cache:      15486      16556
Swap:         4095       1405       2690
```

Comment: Ejabberd tries to use more memory than you actually have. What is the output of `free -m`

Comment: @GaneshGodshelwar please update your question with new info, and format it correctly.

Comment: updated @SorenA